# Problemas en github con git

Tags: git, github

El problema es que cuando subo un repositorio a github con git al momento de revisar las contribuciones me sale otra persona que no soy yo, y no entiendo a qué se debe si cuando me logeo lo hago con mi cuenta de github, ya cerré quite las credenciales varias veces en git y aun así sigue el problema

Mi nombre en github no es kiren97 y aun así sale que esa persona subió el repositorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si al decir que ya te loggeaste con tu usuario en git te refieras a establecer la configuración de usuario pero igual revisa que valores tiene tu configuración global y local de git:

```bash
$ git config --global user.name
$ git config --global user.email
$ git config user.name
$ git config user.email
# Para cambiar los valores
$ git config --global user.name "Tu nombre"
# Lo mismo pero con su respectivo scope y propiedad para cambiar el email o las propiedades locales
```

Igual te recomiendo que si estás usando `git clone` con https://github/usuario/repo.git cambies mejor para usar SSH https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh